# Setting Variables in Azure Pipeline Task Failing

Tags: variables, azure-pipelines

I have a simple powershell task in my pipeline definition to grab the date information and set some build variables

```
[string]$buildNum=$(Build.BuildNumber);

$year=$(Get-Date -Format yyyy);
$month=$(Get-Date -Format MM);
$day=$(Get-Date -Format dd);
$revnum= $buildNum.Substring($buildNum.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=major]$year$month"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor]$day"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=patch]$revnum"
```

The task keeps failing with:

*##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.setvariable variable=major;]201910' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)*

*[error]##vso[task.setvariable variable=major;] is not a recognized command for Task command extension. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)*

I have seen the syntax as both:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=major]$year$month"
```

and

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=major;]$year$month"
```

both result in the same error.

[image]
[image]

Build definition
[image]
[image]

Variables
[image]

Comment: I tried it and is working, which agent do you use? can you test another variable name, another value?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - I have tried both with Hosted 2017 and Azure Pipelines vs2017-win2016.  What is driving me crazy is this same task works in a different build definition on a Hosted 2017 agent.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - tried creating another powershell inline task. with just Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=test;]$test".  Still fails.

Comment: Hi JDBennett - could you show the definition of your powershell task? There might be clues in there.

Comment: this wouldn't be a direct answer to your question,but i think what you are doing can be solved with gitversion in a much better fashion, or just straight out [azure devops build naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: @JDBennett Try to run with debug=true and check the logs

Comment: @4c74356b41 - That is what I normally do.  However this is a NuGet library that we publish as part of our internal framework.  I want to be able (1) have a default SemVer version number:  YYMM.DD.REV-beta as part of our CI/CD AND be able set the version number at queue time so I can specify the release version number vs it being set in the .proj file.

Comment: @VinceBowdren - added the details of the PS task.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - debug doesn't show much.  Added the additional image.  Still the same error.  Claiming the Task is not defined.

Comment: Try to create a new pipeline with only the script, if it will work add the other tasks.

Comment: I test it on my side and is working too. Did you try to use self-hosted agent? Did you still get the same error? With Hoested agent, each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. So it might be the problem.

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT - Yes I tried it with a self hosted agent and I still get the error.  I have tried creating a new pipeline with just the powershell script.  Nothing works.  This is completely baffling.

Comment: @JDBennett I wonder if that could be a different symbol in the command name, which looks like the normal English letter, but in fact, has a different code. It often happens with quotes, when you copy the text from somewhere, but might be the case with other characters... Can you try to literally re-type the command - everything inside the `Write-Host "......"`?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - Man alive you found it!  That did it.

Comment: @JDBennett Hehe, yet another proof of "copy/paste" to be an antipattern. Happens to all of us, all the time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to YanSklyarenko!

It looks like a copy and paste was bringing in an unseen character.

I manually re-typed it out and got it to work.

Comment: Glad you got the solution. You can accept this answer. I think it would help other SO users who will facing the same issue take more care about whether this unseen character exists:-)